# Named Parameters not Routing in Node using Koa 2

Tags: node.js, redis, koa2, koa-router

I reviewed and followed the guides of:

https://github.com/koajs/koa

https://github.com/alexmingoia/koa-router

https://github.com/saadq/koa-combine-routers/tree/next

I get 404 Not Found when attempting to use Named Parameters. What am I missing?

server.js

```
const Koa = require('koa');
const router = require('./routes');

const app = new Koa()

app.use(router);

app.listen(8080);

module.exports = app;
```

routes/index.js

```
const combineRouters = require('koa-combine-routers');
const paramRouter = require('./param');

const router = combineRouters([
  paramRouter
])

module.exports = router;
```

routes/param.js

```
const Router = require('koa-router');
const router = new Router()

router.get('/noParam/', async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = ctx
});

router.get('/param/:jsonObj', async (ctx, next) => {
    ctx.body = ctx.params.jsonObj;
});

module.exports = router;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "iorejson": "^0.1.1",
    "koa": "^2.2.0",
    "koa-combine-routers": "^1.0.0",
    "koa-router": "^7.1.1",
}
```

`GET http://localhost:8080/noParam` -> 200

`GET http://localhost:8080/param?jsonObj=foo` -> 404

Answer (score 0):

The method I was using to call was wrong.

`GET http://localhost:8080/param/foo` -> 200